# Hey <REACT/> stucked while passing the multiple JS conditional operator inside JSX Element { user && Go for next conditional operator }

Tags: mern

**Hey   stucked while passing the multiple JS conditional operator inside JSX Element  { user && Go for next conditional operator }**

--> {user && {post.username === user.username && (  <---

```
                        <i
                          className=" singlePostIcon fas fa-edit" onClick={() => setUpdateMode(true)}
                        ></i>

     <i className=" singlePostIcon far fa-trash-alt"
                          onClick={handleDelete}
                        ></i>

                          </div>
                    )} }


ERROR : AT LINE 75 :25 
          ./src/components/SinglePost/Singlepost.jsx
SyntaxError: D:\MERN_BLOG\Client\src\components\SinglePost\Singlepost.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (75:27)

  73 |             {title}
  74 |
> 75 |   {user && {post.username === user.username && (
     |                 ^        
  76 |                       <div className="singlePostEdit">
  77 | <i
  78 |                           className=" singlePostIcon fas fa-edit"
```

Comment: you dont need `{` here in {post.username since whole thing is wrapped in {user &&

and also u don't need ( after &&

Comment: thanks @SamiUllah  it worked ferfectly